# How to block execution till you obtain user's heading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   //Set up MapView
   //Set up LocationManager
}

-(IBAction)currentLocation:(id)sender
{
   //Start headings for LocationManager
   //MyCode
     .
     .
     .
   //Need to get the user's heading and continue the code
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *) newHeading
{
    //Successfully get heading
}
```

Now, I need to get the heading back in the `currentLocation` method. I found the following options:

1. Dispatch blocks (I currently have no idea about how to use them, and wondering if they are really necessary).
2. Continue the code in the method `locationManager`. This can be done, but it would be better if I can bring the variable `heading` back into `currentLocation` method and continue my code.

I know there are lot of questions on this topic, but I could not take help from any of those solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: I presume that your `currentLocation` method is being triggered by some user interface element (since it is an `IBAction`) and this is when you start the location manager gathering heading information?  If so, then you should continue your code in the `didUpdateHeading` method, or a method that you trigger from that method.  You should program in an event-driven way.  `currentLocation` is triggered by an appropriate user action, starts location processing and then it should exit.  When heading information is available, that event will trigger `didUpdateHeading`.

Comment: @Paulw11 Here is the situation. In the `currentLocation` method, I do some processing and after that I need user's heading, then rest of the code continues. If I put the code in `didUpdateHeading`, it will be called again when user changes his heading, which I DON'T want. I guess I should not name the method `currentLocation`, that is misleading. Anyway, I hope the scenario is clear.

Comment: The problem is that getting a heading could take a long time, so if you block in the `currentLocation` method you will cause your app to hang (because you are executing on the main thread).  A better approach would be to enable heading collection in a method like `viewDidAppear` and disable the UI element that triggers `currentLocation`. Once you have received your first heading update, enable the UI that triggers `currentLocation` as you know that a heading value will be available.  In your `didUpdateHeading` store the current heading in a property for use in your other method

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to iOS. Could you give me some directions as to how do I implement it? Specifically: 1. How do I, "disable the UI element that triggers currentLocation."   2. How to enable the UI that triggers `currentLocation` once I know that heading is available? `currentLocation` is triggered by a button which user can press anytime.  3. How, "In your didUpdateHeading store the current heading in a property for use in your other method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a property to store your heading - before the @implementation *Classname* in your Classname.m file add -

```
@interface classname ()     // Change classname to *your* class name

@property (retain,nonatomic) CLHeading *currentHeading;

@end
```

Then in your `viewWillAppear` method -

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   self.theButton.enabled=NO;             //This is the button that triggers your `currentLocation` method

   if (locationManager.headingAvailable) {
       [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
   }
   else  {
       // Possibly display some alert that heading information is not supported
   }
}
```

Your didUpdateHeading method will be -

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *) newHeading
{
    self.currentHeading=newHeading;
    self.theButton.enabled=YES;            //Since we now have a heading value we can enable the button
}
```

Your `currentLocationMethod` can now use the value from `self.currentHeading` when it needs the heading

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some changes to the button since it was not declared programatically. I couldn't access it as `self.theButton`, but I did it as, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO`.